# How do I use a custom KryptonPalette in a Windows Forms project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, krypton-toolkit

I have designed a custom palette and exported it into its own .xml file using the Krypton Toolkit Palette Designer, and I would like my main's program's global palette to be set to this custom palette.

Currently, this is how I am applying the global palette to my main program.cs:

```
Program.LookAndFeel = new ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager();
Program.LookAndFeel.GlobalPalette = ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager.PaletteProfessionalSystem;
```

The idea is to replace the "PaletteProfessionalSystem" with my "CustomPalette". I was thinking of declaring my customPalette in its own C# class file, and do something like this:

```
public class CustomPalette : PaletteProfessionalSystem
    {
        public CustomPalette()
        {
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream("customPalette.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                // create new CustomPalette using stream
            }
        }
    }
```

And updating my main program's global palette:

`Program.LookAndFeel.GlobalPalette = new CustomPalette();`

However, I am unsure as to how to create a new CustomPalette class from the .xml file. Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Comment: `Program.LookAndFeel.GlobalPalette = new CustomPalette();`